# Flash attributes not working over https - works with http

Tags: java, spring, https, openshift

I have a spring webapp running locally. It works perfectly fine and passes the flash attributes through to the other controller on redirect perfectly.

When I throw this up on openshift, the flash attribute functionality stops working all together when using an https route. If I use an http route, though, it still works fine.

This is my redirect pass through method, it takes in an id in the path, does some logic and redirects to the /foo endpoint, passing through someVariable.

```
@GetMapping("/foo/{someId}")
public ModelAndView redirectFoo(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, @PathVariable(value = "someId") String someId, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
    //..some logic
    attributes.addFlashAttribute("someVariable", someVariable);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/foo");
}
```

redirectFoo redirects to /foo and passes in someVariable through the flash attributes to /foo

```
@GetMapping("/foo")
public ModelAndView get(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, @ModelAttribute("someVariable") String someVariable) {
    //...some logic with someVariable...
    return new ModelAndView("foo");
}
```

This all works perfectly fine locally. But when I have it up on openshift, it doesn't work right.

*EDIT: this doesn't seem to be an openshift issue, but moreso an https issue. If i use an http route, the flash attributes work correctly. If i use an https route, they do not.

Comment: can you make a curl -Iv with the https route?

Comment: Your application likely has to be configured to honour the ``X-Forwarded-Proto`` header which indicates what protocol the external router is terminating and use it when constructing full URLs in responses. Right now it may be responding with ``http`` URLs all the time in responses instead of ``https`` when access via a service route.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton that's exactly what's happening, you're right. When it redirects it redirects to an `http` URL instead of the `https`. Do you know off the top of your head how to configure that?

Answer (score 0):

As Graham said in the comments, it was an issue with my app redirecting to `http` instead of `https`. To resolve this, I just needed to change the redirect method to

```
@GetMapping("/foo/{someId}")
public RedirectView redirectFoo(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, @PathVariable(value = "someId") String someId, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
    //..some logic
    attributes.addFlashAttribute("someVariable", someVariable);
    RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/foo");
    redirectView.setHttp10Compatible(false);
    return redirectView;
}
```